# BoringSSL - AES implementation

Tags: parallel-processing, openssl, aes

I am looking into the BoringSSL library in order to understand the implementation of AES:

https://github.com/google/boringssl/tree/master/crypto/fipsmodule/aes

In this folder the [`aes.c`](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/crypto/fipsmodule/aes/aes.c) file is responsible for encrypting / decrypting etc. It usually takes a 128bit input (and key) and provides an encrypted / decrypted output. It checks if any hardware-optimization is possible and eventually runs the right assembler code for the AES-encryption/decryption.

There is also the file [`mode_wrappers.c`](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/crypto/fipsmodule/aes/mode_wrappers.c) which provides the different modes (CBC, CTR, etc.). But at which point is the input divided in the 128bit blocks that are encrypted/decrypted with the `aes.c` file?
Are the CTR and the ECB-Mode parallelized in this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where the message input is split into blocks is only one `#include` away: you can see this happening in the `modes` source folder, e.g. [this one for CTR mode](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/crypto/fipsmodule/modes/ctr.c).

Note that BoringSSL is not meant as a generic crypto API:

> Although BoringSSL is an open source project, it is not intended for general use, as OpenSSL is.

---

In general AES isn't parallelized, even if the mode allows for parallelization. This is basically because "native" AES implementations are easily fast enough to handle any I/O. It can clearly be seen from the file indicated for CTR that no parallelization takes place. Remember that TLS records are relatively small, so splitting and recombining them would take too much time anyway: instead you'd want low latency packet encryption.

So for TLS it is fine to encrypt entire data records using single threaded AES. If there are multiple TLS sessions then the different sessions will likely use different threads / cores, so parallelization basically comes "for free".

In cases where the CPU usage may become an issue like SSD's the AES is usually provided by the hardware.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. So is it safe to assume, that if I am using a browser that uses BooringSSL for the AES-encryption there is no parallelism. So for the optimization, “only” AES-NI instructions are used (if available).

Comment: Yes, basically that's about it. Don't know if browsers use BoringSSL (with one O), Chromium uses OpenSSL it seems, Firefox probably still uses NSS and Edge probably WinSocket or something but yeah, I guess the above still goes for all of them.

Comment: I also looked a bit into OpenSSL, for encrypting with AES there is no use of bitslicing technique. I guess that's also because of the limited amount of data you have to encrypt. It kind of makes sense because you are limited anyway when you are using the internet because of the max. bytes a frame is allowed to have.

Comment: Yeah, usually each frame should be around 1.5 kB (assuming the message is large) and then there is AES-NI with many GB / s. Diminishing returns and a more complex implementation mainly to save a few micro-seconds at best for older CPU's without hardware acceleration.